# Invalid read of size 1 in tetris using valgrind

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, tetris

I am trying to write a tetris dynamic 2D array of rows and cols named data; I make a function called edit_2Darray to duplicate the original 2D array and make each column longer, and for the rest I fill with space;

```
==21909== Invalid read of size 1
==21909==    at 0x100002C0A: Tetris::print() const (main.cpp:300)
==21909==    by 0x1000011CB: test_example() (main.cpp:59)
==21909==    by 0x100001053: main (main.cpp:36)
==21909==  Address 0x10080a9c1 is 1 bytes inside a block of size 2 free'd
==21909==    at 0x1000132F7: free (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==21909==    by 0x100005188: Tetris::edit_2Darray(int, int) (tetris.cpp:214)
==21909==    by 0x1000056EC: Tetris::add_piece(char, int, int) (tetris.cpp:279)
==21909==    by 0x10000118F: test_example() (main.cpp:57)
==21909==    by 0x100001053: main (main.cpp:36)
==21909==  Block was alloc'd at
==21909==    at 0x100012EBB: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.11.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==21909==    by 0x10005743D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib)
==21909==    by 0x1000050DD: Tetris::edit_2Darray(int, int) (tetris.cpp:208)
==21909==    by 0x1000056EC: Tetris::add_piece(char, int, int) (tetris.cpp:279)
==21909==    by 0x10000118F: test_example() (main.cpp:57)
==21909==    by 0x100001053: main (main.cpp:36)
==21909==
```

Here are my add_piece function for I size piece and edit_2Darray();

```
private:
int width;
int* heights;
char** data;

Tetris::Tetris(int aWidth) {
  width = aWidth;
  heights = new int[aWidth];
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < aWidth; i++) {
      heights[i] = 0;
  }
  data = new char* [aWidth];
  for (unsigned int j = 0; j < aWidth; j++) {
      data[j] = new char[1];
      data[j][0] = ' ';
  }
}

void Tetris::add_piece(char c, int m, int n) {
int l = 0;
int max_h = 0;
if (m != 0 &&
    m != 90 &&
    m != 180 &&
    m != 270) {
    cerr << "INCORRECT ANGLE!" << endl;
}
if (n < 0 ||
    n > width-1) {
    cerr << "INCORRECT POSITION" << endl;
}
if (c == 'I') {
    if (m == 0 || m == 180) {
        max_h = get_max_height();
        heights[n] += 4;
        if (heights[n] >= max_h) {
            edit_2Darray(heights[n], heights[n] - max_h);
        }
        data[n][heights[n]-4] = c;
        data[n][heights[n]-3] = c;
        data[n][heights[n]-2] = c;
        data[n][heights[n]-1] = c;
    }
    if (m == 90 || m == 270) {
        l = 0;
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (l < heights[n+k]) {
                l = heights[n+k];
            }
        }
        max_h = get_max_height();
        heights[n] = l+1;
        heights[n+1] = heights[n];
        heights[n+2] = heights[n];
        heights[n+3] = heights[n];
        if (heights[n] >= max_h) {
            edit_2Darray(heights[n], heights[n] - max_h);
        }
        data[n][heights[n]-1] = c;
        data[n+1][heights[n]-1] = c;
        data[n+2][heights[n]-1] = c;
        data[n+3][heights[n]-1] = c;
        }
    }
}

void Tetris::edit_2Darray(int h, int num) {
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    char* temp = new char [h];
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
        if (j >= (h-num)) {
            temp[j] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            temp[j] = data[i][j];
        }
    }
    delete[] data[i];
    data[i] = temp;
    delete[] temp;
    }
}

void test_example() {
std::cout << "=====================================================================" << std::endl;
std::cout << "test_example()" << std::endl;

Tetris tetris(6);
std::cout << "empty board with width = 6:" << std::endl;
tetris.print();
assert (tetris.get_width() == 6);

tetris.add_piece('O',0,1);
std::cout << "after adding first piece:" << std::endl;
tetris.print();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Do you want to know what the error means or do you already know? Do you want suggestions for how to debug it or have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Valgrind is telling you is that in your `Tetris::edit_2Darray()` you allocate memory in line 208 and then deallocate it in line 214 (I assume those are `char* temp = new char [h];` and `delete[] temp;` despite the line numbers do not match). Then in `Tetris::print()` line 300 (which you didn't provide) you access that freed memory.